# Logging in successfully redirects back to login page

Tags: php, html, macos, web, authentication

When I was testing my website on my friends Mac, when logging in, it redirects back to the login page. I asked my friends to test it on their Windows computer and was working fine.

Here's my login page: http://nigelsham.co.uk/login.php

**Enter the login details:**

username: jim

password: Test999$

I have looked into my php code and it looks fine. I was thinking the issue could be coming from $ogMeta where it goes to another page.

Here's my login page code: http://pastebin.com/MURVbGF3

The login page should go to members page when login is successful, here's a piece of my membersarea.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!$_SESSION["myusername"]) {
    $ogmeta = '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://nigelsham.co.uk/login.php">';
    echo $ogmeta;
} else{
    $id = $_SESSION['myid'];
    $user = $_SESSION['myusername'];
    $pass = $_SESSION['mypassword'];
    $email = $_SESSION['myemail'];
}
?>
```

Any suggestions on what's causing this problem to happen?

Comment: Why are you using `<meta http-equiv="refresh"...` instead of `header();` ?

Comment: And by the way, it works. I go to `/membersarea.php`. Another note, I can access `/admin.php` as well since you don't set any sort of session identifier to say "Hey, this user is an admin so let him in, but that other user isn't, so DONT let him in"...

Comment: Hi @Darren I did use header() before but it didn't work well when I uploaded the code on to my server. I tried to find a solution to header() but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Turn on error reporting at the top of the script with: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`. I presume you'll get  a "Headers Already Sent" error. I'd be correct actually, since you print out html before you print your PHP. Move the `loginuser()` function to the top of your script, before ANY html.

Comment: @Darren thanks for letting me know your result. Ahhh I forgot to modify the admin.php.. whoops. Thanks for letting me know once again.

Comment: @Darren okay let me give that a go

Comment: @Darren I tested it and it didn't say "Headers Already Sent" error. I put the function at the top before any HTML and working okay atm.

Comment: It would've been that, because you had the html before (content is essentially "headers" when i said the "headers were already sent).

Comment: @Darren hmmm... I also did that after the html and didn't show the error. Might need to re-look and test it thoroughly on someones mac...